# Copying multiple files in waf using only a single target

Tags: python, build, waf

The waf book shows that I can create a task generator which will copy a file:

```
def build(ctx):
    ctx(source='wscript', target='foo.txt', rule='cp ${SRC} ${TGT}')
```

This will result in a target, shown with `waf configure list`, called `foo.txt`. So that I can then do things like this:

```
waf configure build --targets=foo.txt
```

which is all well and good.

However, suppose I want to copy, say 200 files, all to populate a directory within the build directory, let's call that directory `examples`.

If I repeat this for each of the 200 files, I will have 200 targets and hence forth when I type `waf configure list` will get 200 targets and `waf configure list` will be rendered practically useless because of the explosion of output.

But I really want the copying of these 200 files to be a single target so that I can do something like `waf configure build --targets=examples`. How can I do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`buildcopy`](https://github.com/waf-project/waf/blob/master/waflib/extras/buildcopy.py) tool:

```
import buildcopy
...
def build(ctx):
    ctx(name = 'copystuff',
        features = 'buildcopy',
        buildcopy_source = ctx.path.ant_glob('examples/**'))
```

This will recursively copy the `examples` directory tree to the `build` directory. Only one target `copystuff` is introduced.

As an aside, if you want to copy one file:

```
ctx(features = 'subst', 
    source = '...', target = '...',
    is_copy = True)
```

is way better than calling the system's `cp` command.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. The waf documentation is very poor. Stack overflow needs more waf experts.